# Port forwarded but no response?

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, remote-access

I've exhausted the internet and no answer. I have everything set up to reach my ssh server listening to ports 22 and 39999. I suffered behind a DS Lite router, and now I am behind a normal IPv4 NAT router, but still, my port forwarding rule is letting me down. WAN connection is enabled, deamon is running. `ping` works, `traceroute` hangs up with tcp and udp packets before my router, but `nmap -p 22` reports the port is open. Why is noone pointing out an obvious caveat when explaing it's [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379959/how-do-i-ssh-from-school-computer-to-home-computer) and [that](https://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) simple, anywhere?

Comment: because apparently the largest caveat is intermediate routers overwriting anything I configure on my own one, also rather more recently. I even tried forwarding from port 80, which shouldn't be blocked anywhere, but nothing changed. What is happening?

Comment: What happens if you port scan your external IP from a different ISP? does the port appear to be open?

Comment: Yes: `nmap -p 22 <IPv4>` Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-17 12:49 CEST Nmap scan report for <IPv4> Host is up (0.18s latency). PORT STATE SERVICE 22/tcp filtered ssh Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.67 seconds

Comment: Did you install/run nmap from the machine you want to access? what address did you get it to look at?

Comment: did it from everywhere, the host reports itself to be open too, on localhost.

Comment: ok, assuming you've run nmap from outside, then it's telling you the port is closed. You'll need to check the configuration of the port forward AND the firewall of your router. 

if they look correct, then you will need to contact your ISP, as they may be blocking the access.

Comment: it sure was from outside, but it tells me the port is open, doesn't it? firewall is disabled. I can't talk to ISP, cuz the network is not mine (doesn't matter), cuz mine is a DSLite which is even worse. I don't want to talk with ISP, I expect this to work. I don't believe I can't make it work.

Comment: PORT STATE SERVICE 22/tcp filtered :- indicates something is blocking the communication. If it's YOUR connection and YOUR router, then you shuold be able to talk to the ISP to get them to check. You'll also need to check on the network you are connecting from.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this??

Comment: Hi, thanks, I called my ISP afterall and made them change my DSLite to normal ipv4-cgn, which worked. The other "normal network" i tried using (which i now confess, was my neighbor's) didnt get to work. From the traceroutes I think they have a proximate router configured to block incoming connections other than ICMP. The clue on my other question that regarded my DSLite efforts, that my ISP was disallowing me to host services as of terms of use, is apparently not all so true, for it was a flick of switch after my phone call (though the operator couldnt report on the changes he was gonna make)